# Removing/deleting from google datastore using endpoints, illegal arguement exception, delete with non-zero content length not supported

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

### I'm trying to delete objects from the datastore (using cloud endpoints)

I know the connection is valid because I'm pulling/inserting objects with no problem

However when I try to delete using various approaches I get the same exception

```
java.lang.illegalArgumentException:DELETE with non-zero content length is not supported
```

approach 1(using the raw datastore service and the key I stored when inserting the item):

```
@ApiMethod(name = "removeRPurchase")
public RPurchase removeRPurchase(RPurchase purchase) {
   NamespaceManager.set(purchase.getAccount());
   DatastoreService d=DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
   Key k=KeyFactory.stringToKey(purchase.getKeyrep());
   try {
      d.delete(k);
   } catch (Exception e) {  
      e.printStackTrace();
      purchase=null;
   }
   return purchase;
}
```

Approach 2

```
@ApiMethod(name = "removeRPurchase")
public RPurchase removeRPurchase(RPurchase purchase) {
   NamespaceManager.set(purchase.getAccount());
   Key k=KeyFactory.stringToKey(purchase.getKeyrep());
   EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
   RPurchase removed=null;
   try {
      RPurchase rpurchase = mgr.find(RPurchase.class, k);
      mgr.remove(rpurchase);
      removed=rpurchase;
   } finally {
      mgr.close();
   }
   return removed;
}
```

Ive also tried various variations with the entity manager and the Id, but all with the same exception

The object that i've passed in does contain the namespace in the account, and it does contain the 'KeytoString' of the key associated with the object

the endpoint is called as it should in an AsyncTask endpoint.removeRPurchase(p).execute();

Any help suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Are you using a http DELETE method? Afaik GAE does not allow http DELETE requests with non-empty body.

Comment: Yes it is a http DELETE method, what do you mean by a non-empty body can you post an example of a solution @PeterKnego

Answer (score 1):

Make your API method a POST method like this:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "removeRPurchase" path = "remove_r_purchase", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
public RPurchase removeRPurchase(RPurchase purchase) {
   NamespaceManager.set(purchase.getAccount());
   DatastoreService d=DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
   Key k=KeyFactory.stringToKey(purchase.getKeyrep());
   try {
      d.delete(k);
   } catch (Exception e) {  
      e.printStackTrace();
      purchase=null;
   }
   return purchase;
}
```

I had the same problem because I was `using httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.DELETE`. The error it gives is correct. Simply change it to a POST and do whatever you want inside that API method like delete entities, return entities, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying out the following :

`@ApiMethod(
    name = "removeRPurchase",
    httpMethod = HttpMethod.DELETE
 )
 public void removeRPurchase(@Named("id") String id) {
      //Now take the id and plugin in your datastore code to retrieve / delete
 }`

Comment: In the API Test Explorer, when you invoke the DELETE call, can you check what is the data being passed in the URL and the HTTP Body ?